# Need a password to be equal to the date (d/m/y)

Tags: python

our teacher gave us this assignment to make a "password" (not a login, basically make a variable that is always equal to the date and then "if- else" it so the variable is equal to the date )

the code u see is all I tried, I couldn't find anything on the web.

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
xd=x.strftime("%d")
xm=x.strftime("%m")
xy=x.strftime("%Y")
Date = [xd,xm,xy]
password=input("what is the password?")
if password==Date:
    print("well done")
else:
    print("try again")
```

I have no syntax errors

Comment: what is the input format for the password?

Comment: Right now, `Date` is a list and `password` is a string. You'll need to change one to match the other, or they'll never compare equal.

Comment: `password` is a string, `Date` is a list - never will be equal. Lookup `datetime.datetime.strftime` to create a string of your password: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

You're going at it in too "divided" of an approach. You can translate the date into a string all at once:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
date = x.strftime("%d%m%Y")  # will produce '05212019'
# alternatively:  "%d,%m,%Y"   would produce '05,21,2019' - you can customize this format
password = input("Enter the password. ")
if password == date:
    print("Well done")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

Comment: Given the title to the question, they're probably expecting the date seperators also

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for pointing that out. I've added that `strftime()` can adapt to that format if they want it

Answer (score 1):

First `Date` is a reserved word so I recommend using `date`.

`date` is a list and `password` is a string so you need to change `Date` to string

```
date = ''.join(date) # 21052019
```

**OR**

change `password` to list (assuming input like `21 05 2019`)

```
password = input("what is the password?").split(' ') # ['21', '05', '2019']
```

**OR**

don't create a list and just generate the password/date with `datetime`

```
date = x.strftime("%d%m%Y") # 21052016
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which format you're after but you could do something like this and then modify the format so that it looks exactly as you need it:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
'May 21, 2019'
```

You could change to ...

```
*.strftime("%B%d%Y")
```

... for example if you needed it to remove spaces and commas.

This site https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime has a very good format code list (%h, %d, %y, etc...) in case you're needing your time bits in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `Date` is a list and `password` is a string. You'll need to change one to match the other, or they'll never compare equal.

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
xd=x.strftime("%d")
xm=x.strftime("%m")
xy=x.strftime("%Y")
Date = xd+","+xm+","+xy
password=input("what is the password?")
if password==Date:
    print("well done")
else:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.